# Literature for numerical range of a matrix and its properties

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, reference-request, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

Let the numerical range of a normal matrix $A \in \mathbb(R)^{n\times n}$ be denoted by  $W(A)$, and its spectrum as $\text{Spec}(A)$. It is known that for a normal matrix A, that the convex hull of the spectrum is the numerical range $W(A)$. Further, it it known that $W(A+B) \subseteq W(A) + W(B) $, among other properties.

Can someone give me some references of standard textbooks where these properties are given or proven? In my standard textbook Matrix Analysis by Horn and Johnson, these properties are not stated.

Comment: The [Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Numerical_range) cites chapter 1 of "Topics in Matrix Analysis" by Horn and Johnson, so that's one option

Comment: Thanks! I am trying to get that book now, it is hard to find online

Comment: You might have better luck with functional analysis textbooks, which I suspect would cover this. Pedersen’s “Analysis Now!” and Kyrzig’s Introduction to functional analysis come to mind